# Synonymize the tag [tf-lite] with the main tag [tensorflow-lite]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I propose to add the tag synonym [tensorflow-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow-lite) ← [tf-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf-lite)

`tensorflow-lite` has 1,152 questions , a tag wiki and usage guidance.

Whereas `tf-lite` has 298 questions, no tag wiki and no usage guidance.
198 questions tagged with `tf-lite` are also tagged with `tensorflow`.
There's also an overlap of 67 questions tagged with both tags `tensorflow-lite` and `tf-lite`.

Comment: Shouldn't these requests be handled on the [tag's synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tensorflow-lite/synonyms) ?

Comment: @Shai see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work